# spring cloud stream kafka preventing specific exception from attempt and adding to dlq

Tags: spring, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a sample of cloud stream Kafka with this configuration :

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-circular-references: true
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        news-in-0:
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 5
            concurrency: 25
            back-off-multiplier: 4.0
            back-off-max-interval: 12000
            retryableExceptions:
              com.mycompany.kafka.DuplicateReverseException: false
              com.mycompany.kafka.ApplicationException: true
          content-type: application/json
          group: sample
          destination: newsQueue
        newsdlq-in-0:
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 2
            concurrency: 25
            back-off-initial-interval: 15000 #360000
          content-type: application/json
          group: sample
          destination: newsQueueDlq
      kafka:
        binder:
          auto-create-topics: true
          brokers: localhost:9092
          min-partition-count: 25
        bindings:
          news-in-0:
            consumer:
              ackEachRecord: true
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: newsQueueDlq
              autoCommitOnError: true
    function:
      definition: news;newsdlq
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
    listener:
      poll-timeout: 2000
      idle-event-interval: 30000
  application:
    name: consumer-cloud-stream
```

I'm using `spring-cloud.version ->` 2021.0.3.

In our business, we need to ignore all business exceptions like `DuplicateReverseException` for the next attempt and don't put it to `dlq` anymore.

this configuration cover first our requirement but I can't prevent adding this message in `dlq`.

is this ok that I catch this exception and ignore it? Has spring provided a better way for it?

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<News>> news() {
    return message -> {
        if (message.getPayload().getSource().equals("1")) {
            log.error("1");
            throw new DuplicateReverseException();
        } else {
            log.error("2");
            throw new ApplicationException();
        }
    };
}
```